# npm Error Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I received This error when I am trying to run "ionic start MyApp" on windows terminal.

I am running from a new machine and I already tried to reinstall nodejs and ionic but the same error is coming all the time.

Can anyone help me?

```
npm WARN tar invalid entry

    > node-sass@4.9.0 install C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Kokua App\KokuaApp1\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    module.js:549
         throw err;
         ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'minimatch'
         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
         at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
         at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Kokua
    App\KokuaApp1\node_modules\true-case-path\node_modules\glob\glob.js:44:17)
         at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
         at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.10.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not
    permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Kokua App\KokuaApp1\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
    {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-13T23_54_19_462Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the problem with those steps:

```
$ npm uninstall cordova ionic
$ npm cache clean -f
$ npm install npm -g
```

Then uninstall nodejs, reinstall again and reinstall ionic cordova

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest version of ionic:

```
$ npm cache verify
$ npm i -g ionic cordova
```

If this doesn't work, you need to install the library [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) manually:

```
$ npm i --save minimatch
```

Comment: Still not working... This problem happend when I try to create a new ionic project...

Comment: Can you the check my answer again please?

Comment: Well, I can see your answer but "npm i --save minimatch" do not solve my problem

Comment: When i try to "ionic serve" this project created this error appears: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Kokua App\KokuaApp1\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'

Comment: For that error run this command   $ npm install -g @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev